# How can i rename my default wp-login.php to login?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to rename url of `http://mysite/wp-login.php` to `http://mysite/login`

and also `http://mysite/wp-login.php?action=register` to `http://mysite/signup`

I used following code in my `.htaccess` file but it does not work

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /robin_site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^login$ http://mysite/wp-login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule . /robin_site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So is it possible or not if have then please help me ?

Comment: you can try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login-url/?

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Isn't it redirecting? Do you get a "500 server error", a "404 not found", anything else?

Comment: Yes , error showing me like 'page isn’t working'

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still a bit vague, so this is just a guess.

First of all, the order of rules (and its associated conditions) is important, because they will be tried from top to bottom. Furthermore, conditions belong to the immediately following rule.

Since this is a Wordpress site, I think the following two rules, and conditions, belong together

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /robin_site/index.php [L]
```

---

The new rule looks good, but will never trigger, if put *after* the above rules. To have any effect, you must put it at the beginning. Also, there's no need to prefix with the scheme and host, unless you want to force `http` or redirect to a specific host

```
RewriteRule ^login$ /wp-login.php [NC,L]
```

---

So, all rules together, with the new one in front, gives

```
RewriteRule ^login$ /wp-login.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /robin_site/index.php [L]
```